# Django store uploaded file in S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I have this class that exposes a POST endpoint to an API consumer using Django REST framework.

The code is supposed to receive a file upload, and then upload it to S3. The file is uploaded correctly to the Django app (`file_obj.length` returns the actual file size), and the object is created in S3. However, the file size in S3 is zero. If I log the return of `file_obj.read()` it is empty as well.

What is wrong?

```
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

from .models import Upload
from .serializers import UploadSerializer


class UploadList(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']

        upload = Upload(user=request.user, file=file_obj)
        upload.save()

        conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, settings.AWS_SECRET_KEY)
        k = Key(conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_S3_BUCKET))
        k.key = 'upls/%s/%s.png' % (request.user.id, upload.key)
        k.set_contents_from_string(file_obj.read())

        serializer = UploadSerializer(upload)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it possible that something is reading the file object already, perhaps your Upload class save method, and you need to seek back to the beginning?

```
file_obj.seek(0)
```

Comment: That did the job. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use django storage

```
pip install django-storages
```

http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

In your model,

```
def upload_image_to(instance, filename):
    import os
    from django.utils.timezone import now
    filename_base, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return 'posts/%s/%s' % (
        now().strftime("%Y%m%d"),
        instance.id
    )


image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_to, editable=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

In your settings,

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False       # use http instead of https
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False     # don't add complex authentication-related query parameters for requests

AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'KEY'     # enter your access key id
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'KEY' # enter your secret access key
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'name.media'


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'storages',

)
```